# File stream could not be created after deploying war in Grails 3

Tags: java, file, tomcat, grails, groovy

My code goes to the else block at last and logs "File not found" when in war mode (deployed to tomcat) but it works fine in development mode on using the same parameters while calling the method. The file is present in grails 3 default file structure = grails-app/i18n/messages.properties

```
def index= {
        log.debug params.id

        def f = new File("grails-app/i18n/${params.id}")
        log.info("i18n Controller ---" + f.toString())
        InputStream stream = null
        if (f.exists()) {
            stream = new FileInputStream("grails-app/i18n/${params.id}")
        } else {
            ServletContext sc = grailsApplication.parentContext.servletContext
            def res = sc.getResource("/WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/${params.id}")
            if (res) {
                stream = sc.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/${params.id}")
            }
        }
        if (stream) {
            log.debug "Streaming"
            render stream.text
        } else {
            log.debug "Not found"
            render '#Message bundle not found'
        }
    }
```

What could be the reason for this different behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the reason for this different behavior ?
>
> grails-app/i18n/${params.id}

Unless you have done something unusual in your deployment, that path will not exist there and `f.exists()` will evaluate to `false` as it should.

If you ask another question about how to access values in `messages.properties` there are numerous ways to do that, but there is no good reason to try and load resources from that path.

Comment: @rishav-jain If you can articulate what you are trying to accomplish, that would help.  From your example it looks like you want the contents of a file with a name like `grails-app/i18n/42` to be written to an HTTP response.  There is no good reason to ever do that with a file that is under `grails-app/i18n/` in your development environment.  Where the file should be defined will depend on what it is and why you want its contents to be written to the response.